# Finding the equation for a tangent line at a certain point

Tags: calculus, tangent-line

I would like to find the equation for the tangent line of $y=(x^3-25x)^8$ at point $(-5,0)$.

I know that you have to find the first derivative, but I don't know where to go from there.

Comment: $y-(x^3-25x)^8=0$ about $(-5,0)$ is $y-(x+5)^8(x+5-5)^8(x+5-10)^8=0,$ which expanded has lowest degree $8$ in $(x+5)$ and lowest degree $1$ in $y$. The tangent cone therefore is $y=0.$

Answer (score 2):

Equation of the tangent line of $f(x)=(x^3-25x)^8$ at $(-5,0)$ is
$$y−y_0=f′(x_0).(x−x_0)$$
where $y_0=0,x_0=-5$. 
$$f'(x)=8(x^3-25x)^7(3x^2-25)\Rightarrow f'(-5)=0$$ 
So equation of the tangent line is
$$y-0=0(x+5)\Rightarrow y=0$$

Answer (score 0):

Once a value for the slope $m$ is known from the derivative at the given point, use the parameterized definition of a line to get values for x and y in terms of the parameter t and the tangent point (-5,0):

$x = 1 * t - 5$
$y = m * t + 0$

If desired, eliminate t from this system of equations to obtain a standard equation fo the line just in terms of $x$ and $y$.